# Spring Boot and Loading External Fonts: Error Access to Font at 'https://x.com/webfont.woff2' from origin 'x' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, cors

Using Spring Boot and want to load a font through the html file and getting a CORS Error that I don't know how to fix.

Getting the following Error:
Access to Font at 'https://example.com/fonts/webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3' from origin 'http://localhost:8083' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8083' is therefore not allowed access.

index.html

```
...
<style> @font-face {
            font-family: 'Webfont';
            src: url("https://example.com/fonts/webfont.woff2");
        }
</style>
...
```

Spring Boot

DemoApplication.java

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

            registry.addMapping(".(eot|otf|svg|ttf|woff2?)$").allowedOrigins("*");
            registry.addMapping("/").allowedOrigins("*");
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
        }
    };

}
```

}

Comment: Any solution please?